# Tips to improve the speed of full node

Tags: bsc

I am seeing on the last days, my node isn't fast enought to be the first, second or the third person to buy in launch token on bsc, my bot is contract and I think isn't the problem, I have pretty sure is a config on node

My Start.sh configs

```
./geth_linux --config ./config.toml --datadir ./mainnet --cache 64000 --pprof.addr 0.0.0.0 --pprof --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.corsdomain '*' --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.origins '*' --ws --ws.api eth,net,web3,txpool,debug  --rpc.txfeecap 0 --http.api eth,net,web3,txpool,debug --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs --txlookuplimit 0  --maxpeers 200 --syncmode=full --snapshot=true --diffsync --pipecommit  --ipcpath /home/geth/geth.ipc
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want some specific  configs to place on my node, to improve my speed when i snipe a token with contract bot,  idk more bootstrap, how guys can be so fast, if we are using the same bot